# How create init db in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How I can create the initial database on migrations of laravel?

For when I do command

```
php artisan migrate
```

returns me the following message

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE [HY000] [1049] Unknown database
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured `app/config/database.php`? Laravel will not create a database, only tables.

Comment: Do you want create `table` on the db by use migrate?

Comment: no i want create database in migrate

Comment: No, you can't. You should create database use sql command, or operation in phpmyadmin.

Comment: thanks man, any other away to create db in application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artisan does not create the database, only database tables.  You're going to need to create the DB yourself first (in whatever DB tools you have, not Laravel) then run run your migrations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a database through Laravel, you need to have one before-hand. If you use the MySQL default, do it through MySQL and then enter the database credentials in `app/config/database.php` - including what the database is called. (Note that you will also need a user that has access to that database.)

If you have no idea what I'm talking about, you may want to use SQLite, since that doesn't require further knowledge about creating databases, and Laravel provides a sensible default. Again, you can configure this in the database configuration file.